# Calculate time duration based on shift times

Tags: php, time, php-7

I am trying to calculate $work_in_daytime and $work_in_nighttime.

```
$nightStart = '22:00';
$nightEnd = '07:00';

$workers = array(
    '0' => array(
        'name'  => 'Lyons',
        'start' => '15:15',
        'end'   => '23:45'
    ),

    '1' => array(
        'name'  => 'Santos',
        'start' => '10:00',
        'end'   => '22:00'
    ),

    '2' => array(
        'name'  => 'Montgomery',
        'start' => '22:30',
        'end'   => '08:00'
    )
);
```

I have tried following code.

```
foreach ($workers as $worker) {
    $startTime = strtotime($em['start']);
    $endTime = strtotime($em['end']);
    $length = formattedTime($endTime - $startTime);

    $nightTimeStart = strtotime($nightStart);
    $nightTimeEnd = strtotime($nightEnd);
    $dayTimeLength = 0;
    $nightTimeLength = 0;

    if ($startTime > $nightTimeStart) {
        $nightTimeLength += $startTime - $nightTimeStart;
    }
    if ($startTime < $nightTimeStart) {
        $dayTimeLength += $nightTimeStart - $startTime;
    }
    if ($endTime > $nightTimeStart) {
        $nightTimeLength += $endTime - $nightTimeStart;
    }
    if ($endTime < $nightTimeStart) {
        $dayTimeLength += $endTime - $nightTimeStart;
    }

    echo 'Day Time: '.$dayTimeLength.PHP_EOL;
    echo 'Night Time: '.$nightTimeLength.PHP_EOL;
}
```

I am stuck with correct calculation.

Comment: Please update your question to describe the exact issue that you are having, so we can help. " Stuck with correct calculation" doesn't give us any information on what specifically is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try This:

```
$nightStart = '22:00';
$nightEnd = '07:00';

$workers = array(
    '0' => array(
        'name'  => 'Lyons',
        'start' => '15:15',
        'end'   => '23:45'
    ),

    '1' => array(
        'name'  => 'Santos',
        'start' => '6:00',
        'end'   => '22:00'
    ),

    '2' => array(
        'name'  => 'Montgomery',
        'start' => '22:30',
        'end'   => '08:00'
    )
); 
function timetodate($time)
{
    return date('H:i', $time);

}
foreach ($workers as $worker) {
    $startTime = strtotime($worker['start']);
    $endTime = strtotime($worker['end']);
    $length = date('H:i',($endTime - $startTime));
    $day = strtotime("24H");

    $nightTimeStart = strtotime($nightStart);
    $nightTimeEnd = strtotime($nightEnd);
    $dayTimeLength = 0;
    $nightTimeLength = 0;

    /* Night Time Calculations */
    if ($endTime <= $startTime) {
        if ($startTime >= $nightTimeStart) {
            $nightTimeLength += $day - $startTime;
            if ($endTime <= $nightTimeEnd) {
                $nightTimeLength += $nightTimeEnd - $endTime;
            }
            else
            {
                $nightTimeLength += $nightTimeEnd;
            }
        }
    }
    elseif ($endTime > $nightTimeStart) {
        $nightTimeLength += $endTime - $nightTimeStart;
    }
    elseif ($startTime < $nightTimeEnd) {
        $nightTimeLength += $nightTimeEnd - $startTime;
    }

    /*  Day Time Calculations  */
   if ($startTime >= $nightTimeEnd) {
       if ($endTime <= $nightTimeStart) {
           if ($startTime < $endTime) {
                $dayTimeLength += $endTime - $startTime;
           }
           else
           {
               $dayTimeLength += $endTime - $nightTimeEnd;
           }
        }
        else
        {
            $dayTimeLength += $nightTimeStart - $startTime;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        if ($endTime <= $nightTimeStart) {
            $dayTimeLength += ($endTime - $nightTimeEnd);
        }
        else
        {
            $dayTimeLength += $nightTimeStart - $nightTimeEnd;
        }
    }

    echo "Name:". $worker['name'].PHP_EOL;
    echo 'Day Time: '.timetodate($dayTimeLength).PHP_EOL;
    echo 'Night Time: '.timetodate($nightTimeLength).PHP_EOL.PHP_EOL;
}
```

https://www.tehplayground.com/CkZ53jjD1cyFEymB

earlier post:
Disregard ----  https://www.tehplayground.com/PohT0L7s35m9VKOe

Like this?
Although I haven't adjusted it, but i think i need to change it a bit more to get it correctly for the turn of the new day (it doesnt see it as a continous shift i dont think)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 0):

- The variable `$em` is undefined.
- Unsure of what your constants are for daytime and nighttime, but
  assuming you calculate daytime from 6am to 6pm and night time from
  6pm to 6am:

---

```
<?php
$start_nighttime = strtotime('18:00');
$end_nighttime = strtotime('05:59');
$start_daytime = strtotime('06:00');
$end_daytime = strtotime('17:59');

foreach($worker as $data){
       $worker_start = strtotime($data['start']);
       $worker_end = strtotime($data['end']);
       if ($worker_start > $start_daytime && $worker_end < $start_nighttime) {
          //Worked only during the day
          $daytime = round(abs($worker_start - $worker_end) / 60, 2);
       } elseif ($worker_start > $start_daytime && $worker_end > $end_nighttime) {
         //Worked during the day and extended past defined night time
         $daytime = round(abs($worker_start - $end_daytime) / 60, 2);
         $nighttime = round(abs($start_nightime - $worker_end) / 60, 2);
       } elseif ($worker_start > $start_nighttime && $worker_end < $end_nighttime){
         //Worked only during the night
         $nighttime = round(abs($worker_start - $worker_end));
       } elseif ($worker_start > $start_nighttime && $worker_end > $end_nighttime){
         //Worked only during the night up until the moring
         $nighttime = round(abs($worker_start - $end_nighttime));
         $daytime = round(abs($start_daytime - $worker_end));
       }
}
?>
```

Comment: Also avoid posting duplicate questions otherwise likely to get flagged : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46352726/calculate-time-length-based-on-two-given-times

Comment: `$nightStart = '22:00'; $nightEnd = '07:00';`  and rest hours are day time.

Comment: then you need to break up the night shift hours to be either side of 00:00 hours. put the values into arrays and handle that way. 
because 22:00-24:00 does not roll into 07:00 in time function. if it had the date as well yes, but not as hours/minutes on their own.

Comment: @CraigB 24 -22 should give you 120. Or do you mean PHP won't represent 00:00 as 24:00?

Comment: @seoppc then change as appropriate in the code. Also let me know whether this works as I didn't try it. Just wrote it from what I know.

Comment: @user145490 i mean that when there is a shift running past midnight, basic maths wont function as a endtime - starttime as realistically for the shift the clock if its 22:00  start till 08:00 finish, the 08:00 would be 32:00 hours, see my example below, i had that working for me